# Verizon overbilling me?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have verizon air card for my internet. Which is called vz manager. I have had it for about a year. Keeping within my usage allowance the whole time until 3 months ago, when my bill came in my 5,000 g allowance was ran to 18,000.

It has continued to do so through the last 3 months. My usage reset itself yesterday for the new month. I got on google for about 5 minutes and chatted for about an hour yesterday online. Mind you that I have never done anything any different then i do everyday.

I do not download music or watch videos on my computer, nothing like that. Well since last night a 8 pm my usage sayd 1109.525 gb. ALREADY! For being on the internet for an hour with no downloads. What could be causing this, please thrown me some ideas.

Verizon is checking on the problem, but that usually doesnt get me the answer i want. Can someone be hacking my card and using internet through it, has told me that that is not possible, however I think with the internet anytihng is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you were infected with a [DDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS) bot which uses your bandwidth for attacking servers. Try scanning with [Avast!](http://avast.com) — it's free but powerful.

If you have a wireless access point — make sure it's protected with a good password, and WPA, not WEP: WEP is weak and easy to hack through.